# SSO for a tomcat hosted webapp with Azure ADFS

Tags: tomcat, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs

I have my application hosted on Tomcat which needs to perform a SAML based authentication. My organisation's AD services are federated through Azure ADFS.

Is there a choice of an adapter which readily integrates with Tomcat. My application will use close to 1500 users on LIVE platform. I am not planning to use Apache httpd services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite different Java-based SAML protocol implementations available. Some only covers basic SAML protocol (like OpenSAML) some provided a full SAML SP.

It basically depends on what your web app is already using.

IMHO Spring Security SAML extension is the best and most complete SAML SP implementation. The next one might be 'Keycload Tomcat adapter' (questional future as IBM took over RedHat?). OIOSAML, .....